# WicketTester for page update: assert locale change

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

I'm changing the sites locale with an AjaxLink:

```
@Override
public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    Session.get().setLocale(newLanguage.getLocale());
    // Add whole page to update instead of single components
    target.add(getPage());
}
```

It does work as i expect, every i18n string on the entire page gets updated while form contents are kept. Splendid.

But testing with WicketTester won't work out. Both methods, clickLink and executeAjaxBehavior, do trigger the AjaxLink, but WicketTester doesn't detect any changes for the model value.

```
@Test
public void check() {
    tester.startPage(SwitchLangPage.class);
    tester.clickLink("link", true);
    tester.assertModelValue("link:label", "English");
}
```

Am I missing something importent here?

(Wicket 6.19)

Edit: [Gist with a simplified panel](https://gist.github.com/LeRisto/69ca2bf8961646c34664)

Comment: How is the label put to the link? (can you paste that bit of code?)

Comment: Mmm. Looks allright to me (except for the typo's ;)) . If I have time I will check it today, as I have something similar in my app

Comment: Maybe (not sure) you are bitten by the `setReuseItems()`?

Comment: @RobAu: i didn't touch the `resuseItems` flag. Which typos? I tried to summarize the class in the gist editor instead of an IDE ...

Comment: 2 questions: a.) In your question you don't seem to be using a Repeater? b.) From your gist I can't tell why the link would actually change. It remains the same. This would be different if you would display the current locale of the session

Comment: a) i didn't include the repeater in the questions code, because i thought the ajax part of the ajaxlink is the interesting code snippet.
b) the ajaxlink changes the sessions locale and adds the whole page to the update, making an update to the complete page thus updating all i18n labels with the new locales string - which works like a charm, but is not trackable with wickettester (for me at least).

Comment: `AbstractReasyOnlyModel`

Comment: Hmm I've tried testing your exact panel and I am unable to not get it to work. I've created all relevant files on gist as well ... we might get closer to the problem by comparing the differences? (Obviously your panel is simplified and the key part might be missing) https://gist.github.com/twendelmuth/f4eb64a99f54d41c8c56